# Delete all rows containing a specific number across multiple tables in a postgresql database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm fairly new to SQL and I have a large database that needs some cleanup. In most of the tables, there is a column called "ID number" and I want to go through all of these tables, check each ID number to see if it is on a list that I have of bad IDs, and if it is delete the entire table row containing the ID. Problem is, the list of bad IDs alone is over 3 million long and the total number of table entries is in the hundreds of millions.  I don't really know where to start with this and was wondering if anyone could help me out?

Comment: how do you know a "bad id" is uniquely referring to a single entity accross the database?  If you were using guids, you'd have a good likelihood it is true, but otherwise, I'd have my doubts.  (An unrelated order id might be identical numerically to a user id, etc.)

Comment: @JayC Hopefully by restricting the changes only to columns that're known to have an implicit (undeclared) relationship to the ID series that's being "cleaned up". If so, it's probably a database that should've been using foreign keys but wasn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with PL/PgSQL, using a query against the system catalogs to build `DELETE` queries with `format(...)` that you then run using `EXECUTE`.

There are lots of existing examples of such dynamic SQL on Stack Overflow, and of how to query the catalogs to build table lists. Use `pg_catalog.pg_class` and `pg_catalog.pg_attribute` or use the `information_schema` for schema info.

Remember to use `format` with the `%I` format-specifier for identifiers, don't just concatenate SQL text with `||`.

See:

- [Dynamic SQL with PL/PgSQL `EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)
- [`format` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)
- [`information_schema`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html)
- [System catalogs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs.html)
- [this Stack Exchange search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=EXECUTE+information_schema+%5Bpostgresql%5D) or [this one](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=plpgsql+execute+pg_class+OR+pg_tables).

Remember: **Make sure you have good backups** before attempting dynamic DML! A mistake can easily destroy all data in the database. Of course, you should have good backups - preferably PITR WAL archiving with PgBarman plus nightly dumps - anyway...